# Negate the following definition of the concept of limit

Tags: limits, proof-writing

[The following is the definition which I am trying to negate but I cannot wrap my head around it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG1b8.png)

Comment: You're not negating a _proof_, you're negating a _definition_.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't help that the definition is flawed, kinda wrong: there should be a "$(\forall x)$" after the "$(\exists \delta \dots)$".

Comment: Please type the content of your question here, rather than simply posting a link.

Comment: What book is that from? :)

Comment: I don't know from where my teacher took it. And sorry this is my first time using this site. I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the definition **should be**:

$$
(\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R},\varepsilon>0)
(\exists\delta\in\mathbb{R},\delta>0)
(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})\,
(\lvert x-a \rvert <\delta \to \lvert f(x)-L\rvert< \varepsilon)
$$

The definition given lacks the innermost "$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})$" quantifier, so that's implicitly an outermost quantifer... anyway, it's a free variable, and it's just wrong.

When you move negation past a quantifier, the quantifier changes: $\forall$ changes to $\exists$ and vice-versa. The negation of an implication $\neg(p \to q)$ is $p \wedge \neg q$. Negating and applying these transformations, we get:
$$
(\exists\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R},\varepsilon>0)
(\forall\delta\in\mathbb{R},\delta>0)
(\exists x\in\mathbb{R})\,
(\lvert x-a \rvert <\delta \wedge \lvert f(x)-L\rvert \ge \varepsilon)
$$